# How to format small multiples column chart to have each chart show unique legend/scales in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I'm having trouble formatting a small multiples column chart.
The dataframe I'm working with looks like this:

```
Parameter   Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6    Var7    Var8
Param1  6.68    7.24    7.16    7.14    5.61    8.25    7.76    7.32
Param2  0.16    0.17    0.12    0.12    0.81    11.32   5.03    1.58
Param3  2.03    2.26    2.62    2.66    4   8.19    5.32    4.09
Param4  0.13    0.51    0.53    0.45    116.32  155.55  66.51   38.1
Param5  8.81    9.33    9.42    9.21    108 42.12   34.63   35.36
Param6  5.16    5.36    5.29    5.46    10.91   5.56    9.88    7.29
Param7  12.53   20.59   27.62   28.82   65.59   3717.04 1372.73 324.31
Param8  15.48   15.98   17.07   17.32   24.5    60.34   31.05   23.59
Param9  13.57   14.05   15.03   15.13   15.13   15.78   17.71   16.48
Param10 7.81    8.95    12.44   12.98   7.16    NULL    0.2 0.24
Param11 NULL    0.04    0.18    0.06    21.02   123.23  62.98   24.07
Param12 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.29    0.83    0.37    0.15
Param13 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.47    0.12    0.07    0.05
Param14 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.06    0.03    NULL 
Param15 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL 
Param16 0.02    0.02    0.02    0.02    0.04    0.07    0.09    0.16
Param17 0.02    0.01    0.02    0.02    0.16    0.79    0.34    0.08
```

So there are not only NULL values interspersed, but also some small and some very large values.
I would like to make a graph for each parameter summaring the row of variables as a column chart.

I originally uploaded the excel sheet into R, then melted the dataframe as such:

```
cpnv.m <- melt(cpnv, id.vars = "Parameter")
```

Creating a new data frame with three columns: Parameter, variable, and value.
I then tried to plot it in ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
require(extrafont)
font_import()
loadfonts(device = "win")

ggplot(data=cpnv.m, aes(x=variable,y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Parameter, ncol = 4) +
  ggtitle("Capinov Water Quality Data") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family="Trebuchet MS", face="bold", size=20, hjust=0, color="#555555")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45))
```

The axes are not scaled to the charts, nor are the columns themselves rendering correctly (see attached image). I was unable to find good examples of code that could scale the axes (both units and font size) to each chart. Is there a better way to produce small multiples charts, or is there an additional step missing from my code?

Thank you very much in advance for any advice.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your data are the `NULL`s. Because of the `NULL`s your value column is a character vector instead of a numeric. To solve this issue simply convert `value` to a numeric.

One approach to tackle the issue with the different scales would be to add argument `scales="free_x"` or `"free_y"` or `"free"` to `facet_wrap`.

Finally from a data viz point of view I would suggest to "flip" your chart, i.e. map `variable` on `y` and `value` on `x` to improve the readability of the labels and the chart.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

cpnv.m <- melt(cpnv, id.vars = "Parameter")
cpnv.m$value <- as.numeric(cpnv.m$value)
#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion

ggplot(data = cpnv.m, aes(y = variable, x = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Parameter, ncol = 5, scales = "free_x") +
  ggtitle("Capinov Water Quality Data") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 20, hjust = 0, color = "#555555"))
#> Warning: Removed 24 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

[image]

**DATA**

```r
cpnv <- structure(list(Parameter = c(
  "Param1", "Param2", "Param3", "Param4",
  "Param5", "Param6", "Param7", "Param8", "Param9", "Param10",
  "Param11", "Param12", "Param13", "Param14", "Param15", "Param16",
  "Param17"
), Var1 = c(
  "6.68", "0.16", "2.03", "0.13", "8.81",
  "5.16", "12.53", "15.48", "13.57", "7.81", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL",
  "NULL", "NULL", "0.02", "0.02"
), Var2 = c(
  "7.24", "0.17", "2.26",
  "0.51", "9.33", "5.36", "20.59", "15.98", "14.05", "8.95", "0.04",
  "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "0.02", "0.01"
), Var3 = c(
  "7.16",
  "0.12", "2.62", "0.53", "9.42", "5.29", "27.62", "17.07", "15.03",
  "12.44", "0.18", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "0.02", "0.02"
), Var4 = c(
  "7.14", "0.12", "2.66", "0.45", "9.21", "5.46", "28.82",
  "17.32", "15.13", "12.98", "0.06", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL",
  "0.02", "0.02"
), Var5 = c(
  "5.61", "0.81", "4", "116.32", "108",
  "10.91", "65.59", "24.5", "15.13", "7.16", "21.02", "0.29", "0.47",
  "NULL", "NULL", "0.04", "0.16"
), Var6 = c(
  "8.25", "11.32", "8.19",
  "155.55", "42.12", "5.56", "3717.04", "60.34", "15.78", "NULL",
  "123.23", "0.83", "0.12", "0.06", "NULL", "0.07", "0.79"
), Var7 = c(
  "7.76",
  "5.03", "5.32", "66.51", "34.63", "9.88", "1372.73", "31.05",
  "17.71", "0.2", "62.98", "0.37", "0.07", "0.03", "NULL", "0.09",
  "0.34"
), Var8 = c(
  "7.32", "1.58", "4.09", "38.1", "35.36", "7.29",
  "324.31", "23.59", "16.48", "0.24", "24.07", "0.15", "0.05",
  "NULL", "NULL", "0.16", "0.08"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -17L
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Stefan. I incorrectly thought that by having NULL values I was indicating to the program that those values should not be incorporated - your answer and axes suggestions really cleared that up.